# PHP or Javascript - Getting values out of a string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
[(33, 165) (1423, 254)]
```

How can I bring the 4 numbers into an Array? I tried with regex so far.

Result should be an array containing 33,165,1423,254.

I can use a PHP and Javascript solution.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried...

Comment: You could match all `\d+`

Comment: Like sln said, you could match `/\d+/g`. As an example, here is some javascript that does this: `"[(33, 165) (1423, 254)]".match(/\d+/g).map(n=>+n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for what you are using this and why you require this.
But if `[(33, 165) (1423, 254)]` is a string, below php code can be used to create an array of the numbers in this string.

```
<?php

$string = "[(33, 165) (1423, 254)]";

$string = str_replace([" ","(","[","]"], "", $string);
$string = str_replace(")", ",", $string);
$array = explode(",", $string);

print_r($array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [0] => 33 [1] => 165 [2] => 1423 [3] => 254)
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
<?php

$string = '[(33, 165) (1423, 254)]';
$regex = '~\d+~';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $numbers);
print_r($numbers);
?>
```